# Ruby: invoke class methods in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a module, whose purpose is to act on any given `ActiveRecord` instance.

For argument's sake, let's say that this method puts the string `"match"` if it matches certain properties with another instance of the same type.

```
module Foo
  def check_against_other_instances
    self.all.each do |instance|
      if self.respond_to? :color && self.color == instance.color
        puts "match"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, I can't just simply call `self.all` here, because `self` is an instance. How do I call the class method `all` from here?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I can't reference the class name directly, because I don't know ahead of time which classes will be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah.. found the solution almost right after I asked...

`self.class.all.each do |instance|
...`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend the behavior of rails classes, then you are best of using ActiveSupport::Concern!

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Concern

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the name of a class from an instance and then [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) it.

For example, given a class `Thing`:

```
t = Thing.new
t.class.name
  # => "Thing"
t.class.name.constantize
  # => Thing
```

Comment: Thanks Baron. Unfortunately, just found the answer ;). Also, you don't need to call `t.class.name...` you can just simplify things and call `t.class`

Comment: This is definitely a much more roundabout way of getting to the simpler solution that @varatis posted.